# Sybase :: starting server created using sp_addserver

Tags: sybase

I created a sybase server using sp_addserver SERVER_NAME.

I have not specified any port, or any other options. Now I see entry of server with class ASEnterprise.

I do not see any interface file being updated. Now my problem is how to start the newly added server?

Answer (score 1):

**sp_addserver** defines a local name to be associated with a host & port of another server (so you can direct remote queries to it, etc.). If you don't specify a physical address or a port number, then your server will try to lookup the information in it's interfaces file.

sp_addserver does not add anything to the interfaces file, and it doesn't create a server that you can start.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly, you changed the server name using sp_addserver. For this to work, you need to:

a. update the interface file for ASE
b. update the RUN_SERVER_NAME file for ASE
c. probably add a loop back server as well.

I have done this many times and above works perfectly fine.